# how to monitor a remote ubuntu host without nrpe from a nagios server

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, nagios, nrpe

I have an nix based host to monitor from a remote nagios server.but i dont want to install nrpe plugin on the  monitored machine.Is it possible? and how to configure the monitored machine, and remote nagios server for this.

See the apps i have on the remote client are all java based ,so I just thought we could use jmx agent only for applications like cassandra,elasticsearch,tomcat etc.
So could you tell me if its possible with nrpe agent on remote client.

Comment: I read somewhere that remote machines custom ssh can be utilized?

Comment: You can connect with ssh using ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub <user>@<remote-ip or Host> and then monitor basic services by using check_by_ssh plugin inside your nagios server.but what about services like elasticsearch,rabbitmq etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can monitor it from the other host, just as external users see it, meaning you can for example test if http is reachable or if the SSL certificate is still valid. Monitoring like cpu usage is implemented with nrpe. So either you use nrpe or only external tests.

Comment: can nagios server contact the direct JMX server remotely

Comment: can you help?@allo

Answer (score 1):

People seem to have forgotten SNMP, it can be utilised to extract information about a remote server for example: CPU Load, Disk usage, physical/virtual memory usage, uptime and bandwidth usage without an external client installed.

Link to enable SNMP on the server you wish to monitor:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-an-snmp-daemon-and-client-on-ubuntu-14-04

There are plenty of Nagios plugins that utilise SNMP, they can be found here:
https://exchange.nagios.org/index.php?option=com_mtree&task=search&Itemid=74&searchword=snmp

It's worth reading up on setting up the security for SNMP, if you set it too open then anything with the correct port access can read information about your machine.

Any questions regarding the set up then drop me a direct message.

Thanks

Comment: yeah I know there are plugins available for nagios however can I manipulate the jmx plugin on the remote client may be using jconsole and then read it from nagios server?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can write your custom JMX script and execute it from your Nagios Monitoring Server.

Plugin check_by_ssh may be useful.